# multiple left joins causing duplicates php sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a html table that displays data from different database tables to the end user.  I am able to get all of the data to display(using jQuery/ajax, php, sql-server) however, some rows are being duplicated.  I believe this to be an issue stemming from my SELECT query in my model(aggregate fanout possibly?), but I am struggling to accurately correct this.  I've attempted using "GROUP BY, DISTINCT" and also splitting the queries up but all with no success.  Here is my code.  Please let me know if more is required.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

WorksheetMdl.php:

```
public function SelectCircuitInfo($circuitId)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT wk.*, af.AcidWeight, af.AcidChillerTemp, ss.BackL, ss.FrontL, ss.BkR, ss.FtR, ls.Rersult1, af.Prefillweight, af.PostFillWeight, af.StartTime, af.EndTime
                                FROM tbl_OCV_Worksheet wk
                                LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_AcidFiller af ON wk.Serial_Num = af.BatteryID 
                                LEFT JOIN tbl_Stage_Check sc ON wk.Serial_Num = sc.BatteryID
                                LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_StuffStation ss ON sc.EncapID = ss.EncapID
                                LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_LeakStation ls ON wk.Serial_Num = ls.BatteryID
                                WHERE wk.Circuit_Id = :cid
                                ORDER BY cast(Position_Num as int)");
        $this->db->bind(":cid", $circuitId);
        return $this->db->resultSet();
    }
```

I also tried using CROSS APPLY with no success

```
public function SelectCircuitInfo($circuitId)
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT wk.*, af.*, ss.*, ls.*
                                FROM tbl_OCV_Worksheet wk
                                CROSS APPLY (SELECT af.AcidWeight, af.AcidChillerTemp, af.Prefillweight, af.PostFillWeight, af.StartTime, af.EndTime 
                                FROM tbl_CellTrack_AcidFiller af ON wk.Serial_Num = af.BatteryID
                                ) af 
                                CROSS APPLY tbl_Stage_Check sc ON wk.Serial_Num = sc.BatteryID
                                CROSS APPLY (SELECT ss.BackL, ss.FrontL, ss.BkR, ss.FtR 
                                FROM tbl_CellTrack_StuffStation ss ON sc.EncapID = ss.EncapID
                                ) ss
                                CROSS APPLY (SELECT ls.Rersult1 
                                FROM tbl_CellTrack_LeakStation ls ON wk.Serial_Num = ls.BatteryID
                                ) ls
                                WHERE wk.Circuit_Id = :cid
                                ORDER BY cast(Position_Num as int)");
        $this->db->bind(":cid", $circuitId);
        return $this->db->resultSet();
    }
```

Image of Results table with Left Joins
[image]

All is correct with it except for the duplicated serial in position 7.

Comment: One of the tables you're joining is having more than a row for the particular id you're joining. You could try using `SELECT DISTINCT...`, but I'd recommend identifying where the duplicate is coming from, maybe an additional join condition needed? i.e.: `...JOIN tableA ON id1 = otherid1 AND id2 = otherid2...` Also select only specific columns you need, rather than `*`, unless you really need all columns...

Comment: Agreed, you need to work out which jon is doubling up your rows and decide what you want to do with it (aggregate it, or select top 1, or add join condition etc). Take out all the joins then add them back in one at a time, and analyze what each one is doing.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT wk.*
        , af.AcidWeight
        , af.AcidChillerTemp
        , ss.BackL
        , ss.FrontL
        , ss.BkR
        , ss.FtR
        , ls.Rersult1
        , af.Prefillweight
        , af.PostFillWeight
        , af.StartTime
        , af.EndTime
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
            af.AcidWeight
            , af.AcidChillerTemp
            , ss.BackL
            , ss.FrontL
            , ss.BkR
            , ss.FtR
            , ls.Rersult1
            , af.Prefillweight
            , af.PostFillWeight
            , af.StartTime
            , af.EndTime
            ORDER BY af.StartTime DESC) AS primary_row
    FROM tbl_OCV_Worksheet wk
        LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_AcidFiller af ON wk.Serial_Num = af.BatteryID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Stage_Check sc ON wk.Serial_Num = sc.BatteryID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_StuffStation ss ON sc.EncapID = ss.EncapID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_CellTrack_LeakStation ls ON wk.Serial_Num = ls.BatteryID
    WHERE wk.Circuit_Id = :cid
) CORE_DATA
WHERE primary_row = 1
ORDER BY cast(Position_Num as int)
```

I'm not sure I full understand the scope of all of the fields and if every field is matching of the duplicate row, but would something like this help eliminate your dupes? Try adjusting what fields are in the partition based on what fields matching in the duplicates.

Comment: At best this solution papers over the actual problem. OP needs to review their schemas, constraints, and query logic.